# MySQL XDevApi Nodejs: How do I turn the result rows into JSON or something the client can check properties and rowset?

Tags: mysql, node.js

Data model

```
sess.getSchema("myschema").getTable("mymix").select(['recId', 'JSONdoc']).execute()
                    .then
                    (
                        goodResult=>
                        {
                            cbFunc(null, goodResult)
                        },
                        badResult =>
                        {
                            console.log("err");
                            cbFunc(badResult)
                        }
                    );
```

then Controller:

```
obj.findAll((er, data) =>  // (er, data) is cbFunc
    {
        if (er)
            res.status(500).send(er);
        else
            res.status(200).send(data);
    });
```

I can see there are 11 records returned, but `res.status(200).send(data);` becomes `{}` in Postman

[image]

Question 1, how do I turn the 11 records into navigatable resultset or JSON back to caller?

Question 2, according to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-nodejs/8.0/module-Result.html, `goodResult.getAffectedItemsCount()` supposed return 11, but is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1**

Assuming you are using some kind of HTTP framework (seems to be the case according to the available details) you can't simply return back to the client the value that gets resolved by the `Promise` returned by `execute()`.

In this case, what you get is an instance of a [`RowResult`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-nodejs/8.0/module-RowResult.html), which isn't directly serializable to JSON because access to the data itself happens with functions like [`fetchOne()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-nodejs/8.0/module-RowResult.html#fetchOne) and [`fetchAll()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-nodejs/8.0/module-RowResult.html#fetchOne). These methods need to be called to build a serializable data structure (a plain JavaScript object or array for instance) in the server side before sending it back to the client.

In this case, the [`select()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-nodejs/8.0/module-TableSelect.html) will yield only one result set, which means you can simply call `fetchAll()` and be done with it, or loop through that result set using `fetchOne()` (check the examples in the documentation). Which means you can do the following:

```
sess.getSchema("myschema").getTable("mymix").select(['recId', 'JSONdoc'])
  .execute()
  .then(goodResult => {
    cbFunc(null, goodResult.fetchAll())
  })
```

**Question 2**

Affected items are only items that were somehow changed by an operation. This is only the case for DML operations such as [`insert()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-nodejs/8.0/module-TableInsert.html), [`delete()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-nodejs/8.0/module-TableDelete.html) and [`update()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-nodejs/8.0/module-TableUpdate.html). In this case, since you are simply retrieving data from the table with `select()`, there will be no affected items.

Disclaimer: I'm the lead developer of the MySQL X DevAPI Connector for Node.js